# Divergence of $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\xi_{m}2^{m+1}$, where $\xi_{m}\sim N(0,1)$?

Tags: probability

This is homework, so no answers please

$\xi_{m}\sim N(0,1)$ and independent of each other.

I think the following will diverge $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\xi_{m}2^{m+1}$, where $\xi_{m}\sim N(0,1)$. One reason is that if it did it's variance will be infinite.

It wil also help if we can show $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\xi_{m}2^{m+1}>0$ (strictly greater).

any strategies?

Any mistake here:
By Markov we get $P(|\xi_{m}2^{m+1}|>2^{-m})\leq 0$ so $\sum P(|\xi_{m}2^{m+1}|>2^{-m})<\infty$. Thus,by Borel-cantelli $\exists$ N large enough s.t. $\forall m>N$ we get $|\xi_{m}2^{m}|<2^{-m} \Rightarrow \sum_{N}^{\infty}|\xi_{m}2^{m}|<\sum_{N}^{\infty} 2^{-m}<\infty$

Comment: An argument somewhat like yours is used to prove Kolmogorov's zero-one law for "tail events" (meaning events like "$X_n$ converges"). In fact Kolmogorov's zero-one law is straightforward to apply in this situation.

Comment: The current last paragraph of the question is odd, to say the least. Please revise this.

Comment: Since $\xi_m > 0$ and $\xi_m < 0$ are equally likely, $\sum_{m=0}^{N}\xi_m2^{m+1} > 0$ and $\sum_{m=0}^{N}\xi_m2^{m+1} < 0$ are also equally likely, so I don't think we can show that $\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\xi_m2^{m+1} > 0$. Also, how did you get that $P(|\xi_m2^{m+1}| > 2^{-m}) \le 0$? The probability of any event cannot be negative, and $P(|\xi_m2^{m+1}| > 2^{-m}) = P(|\xi_m| > 2^{-2m+1})$ is actually pretty close to $1$.

Comment: I think Chebychev's inequality will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is sufficient to show that, almost surely, we will have $\xi_n \ge 1$ for infinitely many $n$. (For then the terms of the series do not go to 0, which is necessary for convergence of the series.) The second Borel Cantelli lemma can help prove that.